# Simple Rspec Length Validation Test - NoMethodError: Undefined method `before' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_2:0x007fb8a24bac00>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm having a strange issue where in one of my model specs, when validating lengths for certain fields, my tests don't pass because of this error. I have three other models where the specs are not having any failure issue, and the validation tests are written essentially exactly the same.

Troubleshooted a bit, changed things (e.g. spec_helper.rb to include `config.include Capybara::DSL`), but still having the same issue.

Here are my tests in `questions_spec.rb`:

```
it "is not valid when title is too long" do
    question = FactoryGirl.create(:question)
    before {question.title = "a" * 101 }
    it { should_not be_valid }
end
it "is not valid when brief is too long" do
    question = FactoryGirl.build(:question)
    before { question.brief = "a" * 501 }
    question.should_not be_valid 
end
```

My failures:

```
Failures:

1) Question is not valid when title is too long
 Failure/Error: before {question.title = "a" * 101 }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `before' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_2:0x007fb89df51c90>
 # ./spec/models/question_spec.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

2) Question is not valid when brief is too long
 Failure/Error: before { question.brief = "a" * 501 }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `before' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_2:0x007fb8a24bac00>
 # ./spec/models/question_spec.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

And my `spec_helper.rb`:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'foreigner-matcher'

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

# Checks for pending migrations before tests are run.
# If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove this line.
ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending! if defined?(ActiveRecord::Migration)

RSpec.configure do |config|

#add Capybara commands
config.include Capybara::DSL
config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

# Clean up the database
require 'database_cleaner'
config.before(:suite) do
   DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
   DatabaseCleaner.orm = "mongoid"
end

config.before(:each) do
   DatabaseCleaner.clean
end

# ## Mock Framework
#
# If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
#
# config.mock_with :mocha
# config.mock_with :flexmock
# config.mock_with :rr

# Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

# If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
# examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
# instead of true.
config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

# If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
# automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
# rspec-rails.
config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

# Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
# order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
# the seed, which is printed after each run.
#     --seed 1234
config.order = "random"

end
```

Edit: This is my `idea_spec.rb` test pair that works with the same format.

```
  describe "when title is too long" do
    idea = FactoryGirl.create(:idea)
    before {idea.title = "a" * 101 }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
  describe "when brief is too long" do
    idea = FactoryGirl.create(:idea)
    before { idea.brief = "a" * 501 }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The before block is supposed to run *before* all tests that follow, so it has to go outside of the it blocks. If the code is specific to one scenario, just remove the before since it's not really doing anything.

```
it "is not valid when title is too long" do
  question = FactoryGirl.create(:question)
  question.title = "a" * 101
  question.should_not be_valid
end
```

Comment: Thanks, slightly stupid question I suppose in the end. I'm just confused because the before worked on other tests I ran using that same format on other model validations? I don't understand why the error would only come up under one model.

Comment: If you post one where it's working, I'll tell you what the difference is :)

Comment: it's working because you're using a describe block and not an it block.

Comment: @ramonrails I reverted your changes since I don't fully agree with the implementation and changes, but I encourage you to add your own answer .